# How to convert string to array in php? form post fields value string conversion to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have post this type of string in Form. Then in server side i get below string:

```
 "[['certi'=>[1],'state'=>[1,2]],['certi'=>[0],'state'=>[1,2,3,4,5]]]"
```

I want this string in array format:

```
[
    [
       'certi'=>[1],
       'state'=>[1,2]
    ],
    [
       'certi'=>[0],
       'state'=>[1,2,3,4,5]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Your string is PHP code. It can be converted to the array using `eval`, but that's extremely unsafe to do with user input. So, why _are_ you getting PHP code from a form?

Comment: What is actually posted? Send it as JSON `[{"certi":[1],"state":[1,2]},{"certi":[0],"state":[1,2,3,4,5]}]` then just `json_decode()`?